# EKEventStore returning empty object in iOS8

Tags: ios8

I've rebuilt my app with iOS8 and finding that the EKEventStore contains no EKEvent objects in iOS8.  With a iOS7 build the EKEvent objects are populated and available.

Anyone know of any key changes to this object in iOS8?

I have verified that I set the Calendar privacy setting to ON (allowing access to calendar) for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the bundle ID/ App ID of the application. I was able to successfully requestAccessToEntityType but no events were returned from EKEvent. The fix was found to be to simply change the bundle id, then to my surprise events were returned. This seems to be an iOS8 bug with bundle IDs.